# Giving the editor focus with visual studio addin code

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I have the following code which opens a visual studio ProjectItem node programatically as a code editor view.

```
void Commit(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        Close();
        var selected = _FilteredList.FirstOrDefault();
        if (selected != ""){
            var item = _Items.Where(x => x.Name == selected).First();
            if (item!=null)
            {
                Window win = item.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode);
                win.Visible = true;
                win.SetFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the editor belonging to the window **win** is brought
to the top of the tab stack but the cursor doesn't give the editor focus.
Any trick to move the cursor focus to the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked for me:

```
    Project activeProject = _applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Item(1);

    ProjectItem a = activeProject.ProjectItems.Cast<ProjectItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.EndsWith(".cs"));

    Window win = a.Open();
    win.Activate();

    _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoTo", String.Format("{0}", 2));
    _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CharRight");
```

You can move the cursor to the required line with the "Edit.GoTo" command.

If you need to edit the code maybe an EditPoint is a better choice:

```
      TextSelection ts;
      ts = (TextSelection)_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection;
      EditPoint ep = (ts.ActivePoint).CreateEditPoint();

      ep.StartOfDocument();
```